# Wordpress Header broke after code moficiation

Tags: wordpress

Im was trying to get the google tag manager code into my header.php and accidentaly I broke the header
I didnt do a backup of the header.php code and I start to modificate it.
Now my website has this problems

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think u don't have "<" on the div or id